# Declaring and using angular directives that map id, name, and ng-model to a single field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I'd like to create/use an AngularJS directive to avoid creating some redundant HTML and also to simplify how I use Bootstrap elements.  I'd like to use a directive this way:

```
<myDirective id="person.lname" label="Last Name"></myDirective>
```

The template I'd like AngularJS to write is:

```
<label for="person.lname">Last Name</label>
<input id="person.lname" name="person.lname" ng-model="person.lname">
```

How would I declare a directive to be able to create this template and have the binding with ng-model still work? Are there any reasons why this would not be a good idea?

Thanks.

**UPDATED**

I added the label tag to reflect how the id/name would be used for the input element.  The generated template would allow you to click on the label and have the focus be placed on the input element.

Comment: for simplification it is a good idea to seperate this to a directive, sure. keep in mind, using a lastname as an id may produce duplicated id's - depends on your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      model: '=identifier',
      id: '@identifier',
      label: '@',
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label><input id="{{id}}" name="{{id}}" ng-model="model">'
  };
})
```

View:

```
<my-directive label='Last name' identifier="person.lname"></my-directive>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/knVkV/4/)</kbd>

Comment: This was my thought initially as well.  However, the id and name properties change as the model changes, which is what I was trying to avoid.  I'd like to keep the id and name to be the passed-in value to the directive (which occurs if identifier is declared with "@" instead of "="), while keeping the two-bind with ng-model.

Comment: Updated so that the id and name don't change when the model changes

Comment: The id and name fields don't look like they work as expected.  I updated the question to see how this could be tested.  With the above answer, clicking on the label doesn't bring focus to the associated element.

Comment: If I change the $scope.person.fname to an empty string (ie '') instead of 'bobby' in the controller, the label/input fields aren't assigned an id of "person.fname".  Getting really close though.  Any ideas why this would be happening?  Thx

Comment: If the fname is an empty string then the id and name will also be an empty string. An id must always be unique on a page which is a flaw in having a directive set the the id to something which could quite easily be not unique.

Comment: The solution relies on the value of the label to be used as the id and name of the element as opposed to the name of the label itself.  ie. the id and name of the first input element should be "person.lname", not "bunny" (or empty string).

Comment: Gotcha. Hopefully this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/knVkV/4/) does the trick.

Comment: Perfect.  This is awesome.  Didn't know the same HTML attribute could be remapped to two different directive attributes. Would you mind updating your answer above to reflect the latest fiddle?  Thx

Comment: Updated with the latest version.